# JSON Parsing error in Java: Unexpected character at position --

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm writing a Java program that goes through all the JSON files in the current directory and parses through them, but I'm having trouble with the parsing part. I get an error on the `JSONObject x` line saying `Unexpected character (�) at position 0.`

BUT the thing is when I manually replace `files[i]` with a string of a file directory, I don't get an error. I only get an error when I use `files[i]`, **but I don't understand why because `files[i]` is a string of the file directory**.

```
File path = new File(filePath);
File[] files = path.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].isFile()) {
        //the following line is giving me the error!
        JSONObject x = (JSONObject) parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(files[i])));
        org.json.simple.JSONArray contexts = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) x.get("contexts");
        for (int y = 0; y < contexts.size(); y++) {
            Object name = contexts.get(y);
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to print files[i]? This probably has to do with how the string is encoded.

Comment: `files[i]` is **not** a string of the file directory, whatever that's supposed to mean. `files` is an array of `File` objects, not strings. You could say that `filePath` is a string of "a file directory", given that it is a string with the path of a directory, but the returned `File` objects reference files, not directories, inside that `if` statement. Also, you don't print the file name, so how do you know which file it is processing when it fails? And you don't specify a character encoding, so maybe it the wrong encoding, or maybe it's a binary file, and that's why you see a � character.

Comment: You need to print the file name to find out what is going on. It could very well be a hidden file in the directory that is causing the error, even though a `dir` or `ls` shows `.json` files only.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! The problem was actually that there were files in the directory that **weren't JSON**, so I would get an error when trying to parse. No more error now that I removed the non-JSON files

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that the error has to be in the name of file (ref: your comment about files[i] and a string representing the path to a file in the folder)

> BUT the thing is when I manually replace files[i] with a string of a
>   file directory, I don't get an error. I only get an error when I use
>   files[i]

, then you have to know that new `FileInputStream(<...>)` has many overloads. Those are not equal paths in the underlying code. When you are passing a string to `FileInputStream`, it creates a File object and the code carries on. So, you could try to compare those 2 and see if they are equal and if they are not, find out the encoding for the current locale on your system. Example, compare: `new File(<string_that_works>)` and `files[i]` for an `i` that correspond to the string under test